# How to implement math graph question generator?

Tags: javascript, graph, generator, mathjax

I want to develop a project that generates graph problems infinitely. The problem I'm struggling with is the representation of the graph. I suppose I can draw the graph of the function, but I don't know how to implement an algorithm that automatically positions characters and formulas on the graph. The mathematical expression library I'm using is MathJax, but since MathJax is not supported on the canvas, the characters must be positioned on the canvas. It's okay to position them, but considering the axes and functions of the graph harmoniously and appropriately, I'm unsure of the best method to do this. Any advice?

What I have in mind is to measure the size of the text and the canvas in advance, and then position it using the coordinates. However, the tricky part is finding the appropriate position. I would like to ensure it does not overlap with the function and the graph.